# NetBeans Swing TextArea is not static, causes trouble

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I have created a JFrame with a textArea called 'outputTextArea' and I want to print the results from a database query in the textArea. However, the variable outputTextarea is not static and therefore I can't call the method setText() in the main method to print the db resultset in the textArea.

I would like to know how I can make this variable (private javax.swing.JTextArea outputTextArea;) static, because NetBeans won't let me edit this variable because it was generated by NetBeans when I dragged and dropped the textArea.

Comment: Did you tried something like ``private static JTextArea hiddenTextArea`` in which you set the text and then just do ``outputTextArea.setText(hiddenTextArea.getText())``?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem.
In Netbeans IDE 8.0.2:
1) In the design tab
2) Click on the textarea
3) go to properties -> code
4) Variable Modifiers -> add static.

It worked for me.

[image: myimage]

Answer (score 1):

Just add an accessor method to your class that adjusts the field. For instance:

```
public void setTextAreaText(String newText) {
  outputTextArea.setText(newText);
}
```

Then anyone with a reference to your class can adjust the text in the text area. Just be sure to call that method from the Event Dispatch Thread. This is usually achieved with [`SwingUtilities.invokeLater`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater%28java.lang.Runnable%29)

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    myClassReference.setTextAreaText("Hello, World");
  }
});
```

See the [documentation on Event Dispatch Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) if this sort of thing is new to you. It's important to get threading correct when using Swing.

Comment: How do I call the method from the Event Dispatch Thread (I know what threading is, but I don't understand what you say).

Comment: Just as a reminder that using this way will erase the previous text on the JTextArea. It is interesting to think if you would like to clear the textarea each time a query is executed or to aggregate new text with the previous one.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to edit codes. 
Open code with another editor just like notepad or something. And if you remove `GEN-BEGIN:initComponents` just before the auto generated code you can edit code through netbeans also.